# Trying to do an SQL injection into a login field

Tags: windows, sql-injection, mysql

I have an assignment to make an SQL injection - I found a login field that spits out an error, but I can't seem to make queries work inside of it. For your information it's an Mysql server. What is the correct syntax to execute queries and grab the admin login or login without the password?

In the first picture I tried to just add a quotation

[image: Login field]

[image]

> Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'version()-- -'' at line 1

Comment: @ConorMancone Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is an assignment, you need to learn more of the underlying function. You have a big helper in that the server is returning detailed error information, in the security world this is a big no-no.

There are numerous SQL sub dialects, but in general what you need to do is:

1. **Break the standard processing**

You've already done this with the insert of the **'** *(quote)* which the server is failing to sanitize.

2. **Insert you own SQL command**

It looks like you already did this as well.

3. **Close your SQL command out**

Often with a **;** *(semicolon)*. You may have missed this part, I can't tell.

4. **Terminate any remaining portion of the server command**

Often with a **--'** *(double dash quote)*. It looks like you already have this as well.

The exact syntax may vary. Watch the error message!

A classic PHP based example is:

> **Normal:** *SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '**timmy**'*
>
> **Injection:** *SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = '**' OR 1'**'*

In this extremely simple case, you don't need any additional breakouts.

Whether you need the semicolon and/or double dashes will vary with the implementation. **Watch the error message!**

Comment: Thanks for this detailed comment friend! It really helped me out!

Comment: Apparently this question got closed for being off topic trying to break into a system - It's just a penetration testing vmware setup, which is an exam assignment lmao.